# Convert Bool to String

Tags: elm

I am trying to print a boolean result onto my screen using Elm 19.

```
result =
  add 1 2 |> (\a -> modBy 2 a == 0)

main =
  Html.text (String.fromBool result)
```

I know fromInt works when the equation spit out an Int but I don't know how to turn the bool into a String for my current problem.

Comment: If it's only for debugging purposes, you can use `Debug.toString` that takes any type of argument.

Answer (score 8):

Converting a `Bool` to a `String` is no different than doing anything else with it. It has just two values, `True` and `False`, and it even has its own construct to branch on it, the `if` expression. It's therefore as simple as:

```
stringFromBool : Bool -> String
stringFromBool value =
  if value then
    "True"

  else
    "False"
```

then replace `String.fromBool` in your code with this function:

```
main =
  Html.text (stringFromBool result)
```

Comment: Yes..... simple..... Could you further explain where in my code I can simply use the above code?

Comment: @LandonCall put it before your code and instead of calling `String.fromBool`, call `stringFromBool`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was obvious from the fact that it's a function definition, the similarity in its name and its type. I've updated the answer to include this.